# Can $obj.psObject.properties[$key].value be abbreviated

Tags: powershell, syntactic-sugar

In order to get the value of a object's property whose name is stored in a variable, I use the following construct:

```
# Create object
$obj = new-object psObject -property @{ num = 42; txt = 'Hello world' }

# Name of property whose value I want:
$key = 'txt'

# Get value
$val = $obj.psObject.properties[$key].value
$val
```

I am wondering if `$obj.psObject.properties[$key].value` can somehow be abbreviated.

Comment: Such as `$obj.txt` or `$obj.$key`?

Comment: `$obj.$key` does indeed return the value. The syntax of this construct looks a bit weird, though, at least to me, so that I missed that. But of course, that's fine with me.

Comment: I actually agree with you, but if it works it works. :)

Comment: On a side note, you can also shorten the object creation syntax: `$obj = [pscustomobject]@{ num = 42; txt = 'Hello World' }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Getting the value directly from a property where the property name (`txt`) is stored in a variable (`$key`) can be done like this;

```
$obj.$key
```